# Memory-efficient absolute difference of uint8 numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer-overflow

I have two big np.uint8 ndarrays, **a** and **b**. And I need to compute: `c = np.sum(np.abs(a - b), axis=(-2,-1,))`

Since they are unsigned, I cannot just substract them. A naïve way of solving it would be to cast them to a bigger datatype:

```py
c = np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)), axis=(-2,-1,))
```

Which in total uses 4<sup>*</sup> times the array's memory. In an ideal world, I would like to be a be to do something like this:

```py
c = np.sum(np.abssub(a, b), axis=(-2,-1,))
```

Which would use the same amount of memory as the arrays. Sadly I couldn't find a function like this in numpy's documentation. For now I'm doing the following:

```py
diff = np.empty_like(a)

mask = a > b
diff[mask] = (a - b)[mask]
# b shape is different but broadcasts to a
# That is why I use mask after substracting

mask = np.logical_not(mask, out=mask)
diff[mask] = (b - a)[mask]

c = np.sum(np.abs(diff, out=diff), axis=(-2,-1,))
```

Which uses is *just* 2.5<sup>**</sup> times the amount of memory as the arrays.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

```
*  4   times = bytes(a) + bytes(b) + bytes(a.astype(np.int16)) + bytes(b.astype(np.int16)) + bytes(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16))
               --------- 1 --------   ----------- 2 ----------  ----------- 3 -----------   --------------------- 4 ---------------------

** 2.5 times = bytes(a) + bytes(b) + bytes(diff) + bytes(mask) + bytes(a - b | b - a)
              --------- 1 --------   ------------ 2 ----------   ------- 2.5 -------
```

Comment: Are you willing to mutate `a` and `b` in place to reuse their memory?

Comment: `np.copyto(diff, (b - a), where=mask)` will use less memory than `diff[mask] = (b - a)[mask]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) provides a very simple and yet memory-efficient *environment* and that could be used here. It automatically takes care of the overflow when performing arithmetic operations. Let's take a look at a sample case and see how to solve our problem -

```
In [63]: a = np.array([3,252,89],dtype=np.uint8)
    ...: b = np.array([10,255,19],dtype=np.uint8)

In [64]: import numexpr as ne

In [65]: ne.evaluate('abs(a-b)')
Out[65]: array([ 7.,  3., 70.])
```

Hence, to get the desired output -

```
In [66]: int(ne.evaluate('sum(abs(a-b))'))
Out[66]: 80
```

Compare against the up-casted NumPy version -

```
In [67]: np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))
Out[67]: 80
```

**Memory efficiency**

Now, let's extend to a very large array and check out the crux of the problem, which is the memory-efficiency. We will use `memory_profiler` module to test out the same.

Python script that has NumPy and `numexpr` versions listed as `numpy_numexpr_memeff.py` -

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
from memory_profiler import profile

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))
b = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))

@profile(precision=10)
def numpy1():    
    return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))

@profile(precision=10)
def numexpr():
    return int(ne.evaluate('sum(abs(a-b))'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numpy1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numexpr()
```

Results on command-line run of the script -

```
$ python -m memory_profiler numpy_numexpr_memeff.py 
Filename: numpy_numexpr_memeff.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     9  63.0468750000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    10                             def numpy1():    
    11  65.3437500000 MiB   2.2968750000 MiB       return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))


Filename: numpy_numexpr_memeff.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13  65.3437500000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    14                             def numexpr():
    15  65.5859375000 MiB   0.2421875000 MiB       return int(ne.evaluate('sum(abs(a-b))'))
```

So, it seems `numexpr` version is taking 1/10th of memory as compared to the NumPy one.

**Performance**

Timings -

```
In [68]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))

In [71]: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))
3.99 ms ± 88.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [72]: %timeit int(ne.evaluate('sum(abs(a-b))'))
4.71 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So, in terms of performance, `numexpr` version is close, but not as good as the NumPy one.

---

Another one could be using the fact that if we feed in one up-scaled one, the other would be up-scaled automatically when performing arithmetic operations. So, we could simply do -

```
np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b))
```

Python script to test out memory-efficiency for this one, as `numpys_memeff.py` -

```
import numpy as np
from memory_profiler import profile

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))
b = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))

@profile(precision=10)
def numpy1():    
    return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))

@profile(precision=10)
def numpy2():    
    return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numpy1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numpy2()
```

Results -

```
$ python -m memory_profiler numpys_memeff.py 
Filename: numpys_memeff.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     8  56.6015625000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
     9                             def numpy1():    
    10  59.1210937500 MiB   2.5195312500 MiB       return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))


Filename: numpys_memeff.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    12  59.1210937500 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB   @profile(precision=10)
    13                             def numpy2():    
    14  59.3632812500 MiB   0.2421875000 MiB       return np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b))
```

On performance, seems slightly better too -

```
In [68]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,256,(1000000))

In [71]: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b.astype(np.int16)))
3.99 ms ± 88.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [73]: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(a.astype(np.int16) - b))
3.84 ms ± 29.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks for teaching us how to use `memory_profiler` - can't wait to try it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself some intermediate arrays with

```py
# sizeof(a)
diff = a - b
# sizeof(a)
mask = b > a
np.negative(diff, where=mask, out=diff)

c = np.sum(diff, axis=(-2,-1,))
```

Or spelt another way:

```
def abssub(a, b):
    diff = a - b
    mask = b > a
    return np.negative(diff, where=mask, out=diff)

c = np.sum(abssub(a, b), axis=(-2,-1,))
```